# How to ID NLA strips for appending elsewhere

Tags: animation, nla-editor, append

I have a source file containing a character and its animated actions. This master file serves as a control repository for the character: All of its actions are kept here, stored as NLA strips. I give the strips catchy names to remember what the NLAs do -- Hop, Spin, Slide, etc:

[image]

When I go to my scene file, into which I would like to append one or more of the actions, I do not see my catchy names, but this:

[image]

Where or how should I ID the NLAs in the repository file so I can see my catchy names when I want to import the NLAs rather than CubeAction.xxxx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rename the action**

You have given "catchy" names to the nla track and nla strip using your actions.  You want to rename your action.

Can be achieved via the UI

In Dope sheet (or outliner) <kbd>Ctrk</kbd> left click the action name and rename

*before pushing down*
[image]

[image]

*after pushing down*
[image]

by putting the dope sheet into action editor mode and renaming

[image]

via the python console, example image below, the action "CubeAction" is renamed to "walk".

[image]