# How to "push up" an NLA Strip or Action Clip to Append to a new file

Tags: append, nla-editor, actions

I want to re-link a library character and then re-append some actions from a previous file.   However, while I see my desired actions/names in the NLA Editor, I don't see them in the Action Editor selection:

[image]

nor in the list of Actions that I could append to my new file from old:

[image]

Unlike [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/99341/111042), I no longer have any list of actions in my Dope sheet, I don't see the Action name (perhaps post is from blender 2.7-ish)

[image]

I can recover them if I append a Scene, but I still cannot then delete the character, re-link, and *find* the NLA Action.

How can I get these actions to be listed as available for Append/assignment?

here is a redux that has the NLA action.  I renamed the referenced action to MyAction.  I am able to see it during an Append: how do I assign it to a mesh?   For example in the file I have 2 scenes, HandsOnHips (with NLA action), and "ref" that has no action. [image]  How can I locate and assign the action to the identical mesh in "ref"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not replicate your situation, in which an action is listed in the NLA and it doesn't appear in the action editor (and this seems quite strange), but, as I can tell from the screenshots, the strip's name is "Gen8shape.handsOnHips", but the action's effective name is "KeyAction", and it's available in the old file "hands on hips.blend" for appending.

If the strip you opened for editing (in green) contains animation data, you can try also to press tab to exit tweaking mode, right click on the strip and choose "Duplicate".
This operation should create a new copy of the strip in NLA, referring to a new copy of the action in the action editor.

Comment: thanks for your time and input, Josh.   I Appended KeyAction, and it still doesn't appear in the drop-down list.  Perhaps that is not an Armature action, although if I select my character mesh (that also has shape-key animation like blinking), it still doesn't appear in the list of Action Editor action menu.

Comment: You could upload a file with the mesh, the armature and the KeyAction, to be inspected.

Comment: okay after some pain i was able to get a small enough file without links. And I renamed the NLA action to "MyAction" and can see it during Append, but cannot seem to reference it.  I note that my file has 2 scenes, one with and one without any action.  How do I assign MyAction to scene "ref"'s identicle mesh?

Comment: ugh: I figured it out; in NLA menu >> Add >> action strip,  will call a pop-up menu

Answer (score 0):

With josh sanfelici's answer I was indeed able to Append the action Clip from the old file, and then with some noodling around (still not selectable in the Action Editor), I used the Add Action Strip in the NLA editor:

[image]

that brings up another select menu where I could see the Action Clip:

[image]